# File structure for Autosar SWC

Tags: autosar

Is there any option through which Davinci tool can generate multiple .c files for a single SWC.
Since I am planning to split the functionalities of my SWC.

Comment: Based on which criteria should it do that?
Basically, when you see a good reason to split into multiple files, your software architecture is probably not sufficiently decomposed.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to decompose the existing component first and distribute the functionality in to different runnables and atomic SWCs. For Davinci only one file is generated per SWC.